# How to calculate the area of a roi applied on an image using python by a known distance of line segmenton the ground?

Tags: python, computer-vision, roi

[The length of the line segment(white color line) in the frame is known with respect to the ground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XGdg.jpg)

Comment: Can you share what have you tried yet and what/where you are facing problems. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried applying canny edge detection and eventually finding the contour edge map. However, OpenCV is failing to draw contour on the line segment in the final stage.